# Laplace smoothing function in nltk

Tags: nlp, nltk, nltk-trainer

I'm building a text generate model using `nltk.lm.MLE`, I notice they also have `nltk.lm.Laplace` that I can use to smooth the data to avoid a division by zero, the documentation is

```
https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.lm.html
```

However, there's no clear example on how to use this function to smooth out test data. Can anyone kindly provides me an example.

Answer (score 5):

```
from nltk.lm import Laplace
model = Laplace(1)
```

rest of the other are same as it is used for MLE